# Linux - How to clone and restore the root(/) partition on a running system

Tags: linux, backup, dd, clone, failsafe

I have a specific situation with one remote Debian(Stretch) server. Mainly there is no one at the site and I need to do some risky upgrades and reconfigurations remotely.

I'm looking for a way to implement a fail-safe system to prevent the situation where I lock myself out.
For example, if after a reboot I'm not able to log back in via **ssh** for a set amount of time that the system issues a **dd** restore on the root partition from a previously done **dd** clone.

The main problem is how to do the **dd** clone/restore safely on a running system. I tried it on my test rig... and it ends up not booting with *"UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY."* message

Thankfully **fsck** was able to fix the issues and make the system bootable again... But this seems to me more just luck than a proper method to do it... On top of it, I was able to run **fsck** manually only because I was physically there next to the machine, which I wouldn't be able to do remotely(maybe it could be scripted)

Is there a way to unmount **/** and do the clone... Downtime is not an issue.. So a solution which would be automated via a offline script is totally acceptable. I was thinking maybe there is a way to script **dd** to run at the very last stage of a shutdown/reboot process, when the partition unmounts, but will **dd** be available then? :-/

Before I go on reinventing the wheel, I though I better ask here for a proven method. Thank you all for any help!

Comment: Boot from an installation or rescue media. Stop using ext4 for filesystems. Use XFS instead. It is much more resilient to this sort of thing.

Comment: I would, if I was able to go to the machine and plug a usb drive or a DVD.... But since I can't get to the machine I'm looking for a remote solution. Maybe It would be possible to create a dual boot environment? So that I remotely reboot into the other system

Comment: Use the remote console (IPMI, iDRAC, ILO, etc)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any at disposal. This remote server can barely be called that.. As it is just a home desktop PC(headless) acting as a server, with no additional special networking hardware... Is there a way to add a remote console just via software, that will run at boot time?

Comment: You can hook up a KVM switch but that also requires its own network access, and someone to physically go there and do it. I expect you are going to have to visit the site.

Comment: Yup I definitely plan on adding some hardware the next time I visit the site, which would render this problem moot. Meanwhile I'm looking if there is some half-sketchy way of doing it with what I have now... Thanks for all the advices(XFS, console...)!

Comment: If you have some spare hard disk space (doesn't have to be a lot), you could debootstrap a basic failsafe root partition -- then if something goes awry during your maintenance, have some grub reconfiguration scripted to boot with the failsafe partition as root instead of trying to dd over an existing root.

Comment: Brandon, I like that idea! Thanks. I started researching the details on how to implement it...